# How to get the touchpad on a Lenovo Y700 to work?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, lenovo

My touchpad is not working on a Lenovo Y700 using Ubuntu 18.04 but wireless Dell mouse works.

### Things I already tried:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You mentioned trying to print the file `/proc/bus/input/devices`. What was the result? Please [edit] your question to include it, don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).